# How to call a oracle stored procedure with RECORD as OUT parameter?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a procedure in oracle database, which looks like

```
create or replace PACKAGE MY_PACKAGE AS
  TYPE MY_RECORD IS RECORD
  (
    first_name abc.first_name%TYPE,
    middle_name abc.middle_name%TYPE,
    last_name abc.last_name%TYPE 
  );
  TYPE MY_RECORD_REF IS REF CURSOR RETURN MY_RECORD;
  PROCEDURE getDetails(
    last_name IN OUT VARCHAR2,
    V_MY_RECORD_REF   OUT MY_RECORD_REF);
END MY_PACKAGE;
```

I want to call the stored procedure to get the data and display them but unable to do so.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The record is there to give you a definition of the result set. Use the packaged types to define local variables which you use when calling the procedure.

```
declare
    l_result_Set MY_PACKAGE.MY_RECORD_REF;
    l_record MY_PACKAGE.MY_RECORD;
    l_name abc.last_name%TYPE ;
begin
    -- get the results
    MY_PACKAGE.getDetails(
          l_name 
          , l_result_Set );
    -- now read them
    loop
        fetch l_result_Set into l_record;
        exit when l_result_Set%notfound;
        -- do stuff here
    end loop;
end;
```

---

> "do you know how to do the same in java? "

A Ref Cursor is a JDBC Result Set. Andrej Koelewijn has a brief example [in this blog post](http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/blog/2003/10/29/using-oracle-ref-cursors-in-java/). Note the use of the Oracle library data type `OracleTypes.CURSOR`. The full sweep of ResultSet is covered in the JDBC Deve guide. [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/resltset.htm)

Comment: I am unable to print the result.

Comment: You need to give me more clues. What client are you using to call the package? What calls are you using to print it?

Comment: It worked fine now. I was trying with MY_RECORD_REF instead of MY_RECORD to fetch the data. 

By any chance, do you know how to do the same in java?